# CURL and PHP - posting multiple array of key/value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, curl

I need to post a form using curl.

Here is the form.

```
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
    <input name="tm[0][name]" value="name" type="hidden" maxlength="255">
    <input name="tm[0][mobile]" value="mobile" type="hidden" maxlength="10">
    <input name="tm[0][email]" value="email" type="hidden" maxlength="255">
    <input name="tm[0][address]" value="address" type="hidden">
    <input name="tm[0][pincode]" value="pincode" type="hidden" maxlength="6">
    <input name="tm[0][refCode]" value="refCode" type="hidden" maxlength="255">
    <input name="tm[0][partnerRef]" value="partnerRef" type="hidden" maxlength="255">

    <input name="tm[1][name]" value="name" type="hidden" maxlength="255">
    <input name="tm[1][mobile]" value="mobile" type="hidden" maxlength="10">
    <input name="tm[1][email]" value="email" type="hidden" maxlength="255">
    <input name="tm[1][address]" value="address" type="hidden">
    <input name="tm[1][pincode]" value="pincode" type="hidden" maxlength="6">
    <input name="tm[1][refCode]" value="refCode" type="hidden" maxlength="255">
    <input name="tm[1][partnerRef]" value="partnerRef" type="hidden" maxlength="255">
    <input type="submit" name="yt0" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$postArray = array(
    'api_key' => api_key,
    'api_secret' => api_secret
);

$data = array();
foreach( $postData as $key => $node ) {
    $postArray[ $key ] = array(
        'name' => $node[ 'name' ],
        'mobile' => $node[ 'mobile' ],
        'email' => $node[ 'email' ],
        'address' => $node[ 'address' ],
        'pincode' => $node[ 'pincode' ],
        'refCode' => $node[ 'refCode' ],
        'partnerRef' => $node[ 'partnerRef' ]
    );
}

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'check.php' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-type: multipart/form-data' ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST => true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArray );

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

I am not sure how to make the array as the keys are same for each array.

I want to create the array for `CURLOPT_POSTFILEDS`.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please show your current CURL code

Comment: What is the problem? Simply pass `$_POST` to `CURLOPT_POSTFILEDS` option

Comment: Ah ok, this is a PHP form to array question, the CURL part isn't actually relevant.

Comment: for me curl works better when I pass query string using `http_build_query` instead of array as CURLOPT_POST option

Comment: Where is `$node` defined?

Comment: @hindmost getting $node by iterating on the post data.

Comment: @web-nomad Why so complex? Why not to simply pass `$_POST['tm']`?

Comment: there is no such thig as `$_POST['tm']`

Comment: It should present if you receive POST request from the form

Answer (score 0):

It is a convention of PHP to map input names with brackets (eg `name[]`) to an array in `$_POST`

If you're trying to replicate the post from the html form you have given it's pretty straightforward, you just need to re-match your post field names up with what they were in the original form:

```
foreach ( $postData['tm'] as $id => $node ) {
    foreach ( $node as $key => $value ) {
        // eg name="tm[1][name]"
        $postArray['tm['.$id.']['.$key.']'] = $value;
    }
}
```

(assuming `$postData` is an equivalent of `$_POST`)

Comment: Can you post an example? I had tried it and didn't work.

Comment: just replace the foreach loop in your original request with the foreach above

Answer (score 0):

```
$postStr = "config[api_key]=api_key&config[api_secret]=api_secret&";;
foreach ($postData as $index => $node) {
    foreach ($node as $key => $value) {
        $postStr .= "data[{$index}][{$key}]=$value&";
    }

}
$postStr = rtrim($postStr, '&');
```

Use below line

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postStr );
```

You have make two arrays one containing data and other one have configuration. It's help you in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the top structure like so:

```
$postArray = array(
    'api_key' => api_key,
    'api_secret' => api_secret,
    'tm' => $_POST['tm'],
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELD, $postArray);
```

Besides that, you should leave the "Content-Type" header in the default setting, i.e. remove this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: multipart/form-data'));
```